# Make a Python variable update everytime the script runs

Tags: python, post, random, python-requests, ascii

I've got a Python script that sends requests, it sends headers and data. I'm able to send, and its working. I've got a **ONE** of the headers that are being sent, a variable. That variable is being appended with a new character. My problem is, it only appends everytime I start the script, I need it to append everytime it sends and not have to restart the script everytime to send a newly generated item. I've pasted my code below

`

```
import requests
import string
import random
from time import sleep

RequestsSent = 0
i = 1

if(i > 0):
     input_string = "guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7a"
     alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
     random_character = random.choice(alphabet)
     result_string = input_string + random_character

data = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"

headers = {'xxxxx': 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx': result_string}

while(True):
     r=requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
     #print(r.text)
     RequestsSent += 1
     i += 1
     print("Requests sent: " + str(RequestsSent))
     print("Sent guess ID: " + str(result_string))
     sleep(5)
```

`

Output:

Requests sent: 1
Sent guess ID: guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7f

Requests sent: 2
Sent guess ID: guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7f

Requests sent: 3
Sent guess ID: guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7f

If I restart the script, then will it generate a new guess ID

I've tried putting the append as a infinite While loop but then that just sits on that forever and doesn't send data, the if statement doesn't work either,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to generate a new random character and append it to the 'result_string' variable every time you send a request, rather than just when the script starts. The current code you've posted only generates the random character once, when the script is initiated.

To achieve the behavior you're looking for, you need to move the code that generates the random character inside the loop where you're sending requests. Here's a modified version of your code that should work as intended:

```
    import requests
    import string
    import random
    from time import sleep
    
    RequestsSent = 0
    
    data = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    headers = {'xxxxx': 'xxxxx'}
    
    while True:
        input_string = "guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7a"
        alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
        random_character = random.choice(alphabet)
        result_string = input_string + random_character
    
        r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
        
        RequestsSent += 1
        print("Requests sent: " + str(RequestsSent))
        print("Sent guess ID: " + str(result_string))
        sleep(5)
```

With this code, the random character generation is moved inside the loop, so every time the loop iterates (when sending a request), a new random character will be appended to the 'result_string'. This should result in the behavior you're looking for, where the guess ID changes with each request without having to restart the script.

Comment: Man i feel like an idiot! thank you! i also put in the data and headers variables in the loop, after the random character appendation happens. Thank you! Just overlooked the idea!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem you expect to have different Guess IDs. If that is the case, you need to generate a random character for each post request otherwise it will only generate one and each post request will use the same

```py
import requests
import string
import random
from time import sleep

RequestsSent = 0
i = 1

def get_random_guess(input_string: str):
     alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
     random_character = random.choice(alphabet)
     result_string = input_string + random_character
     return result_string

data = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
input_string = "guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7a"


while(True):
     result_string = get_random_guess(input_string)
     headers = {'xxxxx': 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx': result_string}
     r=requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
     #print(r.text)
     RequestsSent += 1
     i += 1
     print("Requests sent: " + str(RequestsSent))
     print("Sent guess ID: " + str(result_string))
     sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put string generation under the `while True` loop:

```
import string
import random
import requests

i = 0
while True:
    random_character = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    result_string = 'guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7a' + random_character
    r = requests.post('https://google.com', headers={'xxxxx': result_string})
    print('Sent guess ID: ' + str(result_string))
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
Sent guess ID: guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7ab
Sent guess ID: guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7am
Sent guess ID: guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7ac
Sent guess ID: guest=guest_acc8a45cdf57f7ai
```